# Five squares, each with diagonal equal to $\sqrt{2}$ are circumscribed by a circle with radius $r$.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Five squares, each with diagonal equal to $\sqrt{2}$ are circumscribed by a circle with radius $r$ as shown in the figure below.

Let $d$ equal the distance from the intersection of four of the squares (labeled $x$) to the centre of the circle. Find $\frac{r}{d}$:

[image]

My working out:

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need help finding the radius of the circle

Comment: Forget GeoGebra, you do not even want to make an attempt to draw a neat diagram on paper and label the points and angles. You say it is your attempt but you keep your attempt as cryptic as possible so nobody can understand it.

Comment: hint: $(1+d)^2+1^2 = r^2 = (?-d)^2+ ?^2$

Comment: @someone Please do not vandalize posted questions, including your own. Rolled back.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

A simple approach:

1. Compute the area $\Delta$ of $ABC$
2. Compute the side lengths of $ABC$ through the Pythagorean theorem
3. Find the circumradius $R=OA=OB=OC$ through Euler's formula $R=\frac{abc}{4\Delta}$
4. Apply the Pythagorean theorem to $AOZ$ in order to find $OZ$, then $OX=d$.

---

Equivalent (but faster) approach:
$$\widehat{AOZ}=\widehat{ACB}=\arctan\frac{1}{6}+\arctan\frac{1}{2}=\arctan\frac{8}{11} $$
implies $OZ=\frac{11}{8}$ and $OA=\frac{\sqrt{185}}{8}$, so $\frac{d}{R}=\frac{3}{\sqrt{185}}$.

Comment: thanks a lot for this

Comment: may i ask on what program did you make the diagram on?

Comment: @someone: just Geogebra.

Comment: what would the area of ABC be?

Comment: Base 2, height 3, hence 3.

Comment: oh ok thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I tried to sketch the diagonals from which we possibly can deduce the radius. In your case $c=1$. Maybe this idea can lead to calculating the radius (I am still trying to get more out of it):

[image]

Comment: Label the centre and mark the distance $d$ as per the question. Also you don't need the exact value of $d$ or the radius..You just need the ratio $\frac{r}{d}$ which you can easily get by only a few equations in $r$ and $d$.

Comment: yes will do it - just a moment (I need to reprint the picture)

Comment: hey thanks a lot @EldarSultanow also Aman i only partially undertstand what you mean

Comment: so @AmanKushwaha could you please further explain?

Comment: @EldarSultanow Sorry but I mistook you for the OP

Comment: @someone edit your question first to show your working clearly and the hint given by achille hui is enough to solve your problem

Comment: @AmanKushwaha i tried using that and i got r=d^2+2d+2 and was unable to solve for d

Comment: also @achillehui im not very good at this could you give me another hint please?

Comment: @someone you'll get two equations after finding the "?" in his comment and then divide by $d^2$ to get quadratic equation in $\frac{r}{d}$.